# separate passed array to stored procedure for use in 'select ... like' statement

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, stored-procedures, sql-like

i have a SELECT ... LIKE statement in stored procedure in `MYSQL` for search as bellow:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM t WHERE col LIKE %some% AND col LIKE %thing% ;
END
```

now my question is that how can i pass an array of words and separate them and use them in `LIKE` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call stored procedure store your data (will be used in like '%table_cell_value%') in temporary table. Using programming. Now fetch value from that temporary using cursor.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/05/sql-server-simple-example-of-cursor-sample-cursor-part-2/